# Block logging for assemblies having separate loggers in log4net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have two log files written from my application, which have multiple assemblies in the following manner:

```
Assembly1 log -> MainLog.log
Assembly2 log -> MainLog.log
Assembly3 log -> MainLog.log
Assembly4 log -> MainLog.log
Assembly5 log -> SubLog.log
Assembly6 log -> SubLog.log
```

The log files get written correctly, but the problem here is, the `SubLog` entries get written into the `MainLog` file as well. I don't want this kind of logging duplication to happen. This is my log4net configuration.

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="Logs//MainLog.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%M %date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message        %C, %F, %l, %L  %M %newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="NewForEveryRun" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs//SubLog-%processid.txt"/>
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="Assembly5">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="NewForEveryRun"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="Assembly6">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="NewForEveryRun"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
```

For `Assembly5` and `Assembly6`, I've specified the appender `NewForEveryRun`. In addition to this, I've kept the `root`, so that the rest of the assemblies are logged according to configuration specified in the `RollingLogFileAppender` appender. I guess, the root element is logging all the assemblies by default, even if I mention different logger for other assemblies. Is there any way to block the logging of `Assembly5` and `Assembly6` from root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! The loggers should look like this:

```xml
<logger name="Assembly5" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="NewForEveryRun"/>
</logger>
<logger name="Assembly6" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="NewForEveryRun"/>
</logger>
```

Setting `additivity` as false is the solution. No more duplicate logging :)

Comment: The reason this was happening is because by default [`Additivity`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Additivity.html) is set to true. This means that the loggers inherit appenders from their parents. In this case, `Assembly5` and `Assembly6` were inheriting the `RollingLogFileAppender` from the root logger.